# How to switch from letsencrypt to gogetssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, certificate

Until now I used to use letsencrypt for ssl configuration of my nginx webservers. I have a new server which has a gogetssl certificate, but I cannot install it. From gogetssl I have these files:

- domain-name.ca-bundle
- domain-name.crt
- domain-name.csr
- domain-name.key

What are the steps to create nginx ssl certificates from these files?

thx
Zamek

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I need to merge domain.crt first and domain.ca-bundle to a .crt file and that is the certificate for nginx.